# Create Dataproc Cluster with IST Timezone

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

Can someone help me with the steps / config to createa Google dataproc cluster with IST timezone. By default the cluster is being set with UTC timezone even though the zone is asia-south1.

Comment: The zone is only used to define where the infrastructure will  be created, not to define timezone or similar settings. Also keep in mind that asking for tutorials or steps is off-topic here.